# get data from dynamix ax xml from php

Tags: php

$url = "http://localhost/dss/dss.asmx/AreaCategory_list";

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36');

$xmlstr = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump(  $xmlstr);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the XML in `$xmlstr`?

Answer (score 0):

cannot show data

$json2 = "http://localhost/dss/dss.asmx/AreaCategory_list";

$array = json_decode($json2);
 echo $array->Remark;